Typescript custom key mapping
interface IObj {
    value:string;
    value2:string;
    value3:number;
}
let obj={
    value:"JS",
    value2:"www.google.com",
    value3:2018
}
type kM = "name"|"website"|"year";
const keyMap :{[key in kM]:keyof IObj}= {
    name:"value",
    website:"value2",
    year:"value3"
}
const year:number  = obj[keyMap["year"]]; // ERROR: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
obj[keyMap["name"]] = "Javascript";  // ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

I attempted to customize the mapping or access the key within an object, but encountered an error.
What steps should be taken to address the error stated above?

• kM and key are unconventional names. kM should probably be KM to distinguish it from a value, and key should probably be K so that it's obviously a type parameter. Please [edit] to avoid distractions. • Your annotation of keyMap is the problem. You should consider using the satisfies operator instead, as shown in this playground link.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Before proceeding, please review @jcalz's comment:


kM and key are unconventional names. It's advisable to use KM to distinguish it from a value, and K to denote it as a type
parameter.


The code snippet below fixes the TypeScript errors:
interface IObj {
    value: string;
    value2: string;
    value3: number;
}

let obj = {
    value: "JS",
    value2: "www.google.com",
    value3: 2018
}

type KM = "name" | "website" | "year";

const keyMap = {
    name: "value",
    website: "value2",
    year: "value3"
} as const;

const year: number = obj[keyMap["year"]];
obj[keyMap["name"]] = "JavaScript";

Playground link
The TypeScript compiler struggles to determine the return type with the line
{[key in KM]: keyof IObj}

When defining the object as a const, it interprets the object as a literal.
You can now even remove the type annotation from here
const year = obj[keyMap["year"]];

As TypeScript now correctly infers the type from the object.

I've reviewed @jcalz comments, and they're both functioning well. Thank you

This could be resolved by the Type assertion.
const year:number  = obj[keyMap["year"]] as number;

Please check the TypeScript playground for further referance.

Thats forcing typescript to infer a type, not a very good way to inherit types.
